# Why Can You Expose Private Methods Publically in a WCF Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.5

Why We can put the [`OperationContract`] Attribute on private methods in wcf services. From the day start of my programming i have been taught private methods are those which are not accessible outside the class. Now in WCF service you can expose private method publicly.

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public class MyServices
    {
        [OperationContract]
        private int add(int a,int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can mark your method with this attribute, but it won't be visible to service clients.

Comment: Have you confirmed that that is *actually* callable via WCF? (It may be - I haven't tried.) Fundamentally there's no way of saying "this attribute can only be applied to a public member".

Comment: Then what is the reason behind this it should give complie time error when there is no use of it.

Comment: I have tried it and it works, this is interesting. Anyway you should use OperationContract attributes on methods declared by a service class interface (IMyServices) where may be only public methods.

Comment: @MartinKonopka: please clarify what you mean by "it works". Do you mean that the private method can be called through a WCF service reference, and the private method actually executes and returns results back to the client?

Comment: @aw04 can you tell me one good reason for this type of scenario. You cannot use this method out of the class and cannot invoked by the client?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes, exactly. I have just created new WCF Service project, removed IService1 interface and moved all contract attributes to the class definition. I then added new private method and marked it with OperationContract. Then I created new Console application, added service reference to my WCF service, the private method was also discovered and added in client. And I successfully called the private method from the console application. The WCF service is hosted on local IIS Express.

Comment: Important thing is to remove the interface and move attributes directly to class definition, like OP suggested. Then it seems it doesn't care about access modifiers.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? You're not using .NET 3.0, are you?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5 for both WCF service and console app. Really not the 3.0 like is in the tag.

Comment: Currently i am using .net 4.5 but the first release of wcf is with >=.net 3.0

Comment: Well, the question is probably not why you *can* do it, but why you *would*. You are the programmer, just don't use that attribute on your private methods.

Comment: In addition to what Patrick said, you should be using service contract **interfaces** and placing the attribute on interface methods.  Creating a service without an interface forces you to use **Service References** which have their own problems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure *why* it's designed this way but if you check the source, line 336 says

`internal const BindingFlags ServiceModelBindingFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;`

Note the NonPublic flag in particular.  Then this gets used later on line 678 when WCF is using reflection to figure out which methods to expose:

```
   static List<MethodInfo> GetMethodsInternal(Type interfaceType)
   {
            List<MethodInfo> methods = new List<MethodInfo>();
            foreach (MethodInfo mi in interfaceType.GetMethods(ServiceModelBindingFlags))
            {
                if (GetSingleAttribute<OperationContractAttribute>(mi) != null)
                {
                    methods.Add(mi);
                }
                ...
```

I agree with you it's an odd decision but the WCF devs explicitly decided to make it this way by including the NonPublic flag.

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Description/ServiceReflector.cs,c1358e6f97071bfa

Comment: Robert, for those to whom it's not obvious, you should explain that WCF calls service methods via Reflection

Comment: @JohnSaunders - tweak made

Answer (score 4):

It's interesting to find it works. Surely, you use private access modifier to deny consumers of your class to access marked members. But WCF expose every method you mark with `OperationContract` attribute to public. As Robert Levy found out, it is implemented that way. Similarly, you can find some information in this [presentation about WCF](http://www.slideshare.net/cherviralavm/wcf), especially [slide no. 36](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/wcf-13005350363635-phpapp02/95/wcf-34-728.jpg?cb=1300535959).

When you check the [MSDN article about implementing WCF service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733764%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you may notice they use OperationContract attribute on private method. But it seems to be a typo because the class has to implement methods of its interface.

Anyway, the safest way for you as a developer is to use `ServiceContract` and `OperationContract` attributes in service class interface, e.g.:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService 
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData();
}

public class MyService : IMyService 
{
    public string GetData() { ... }
    private string ComputeData() { ... } // this one is not visible to clients
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 cents:

SOAP, which is used by WCF, does not adhere to the OOPs concepts of C#. Another "anomaly" would be method overloading, which is a very useful and widely used C# feature. While we can overload methods in the Service class, we cannot have two OperationContracts with the same name (even with different signature), which means that we cannot expose an overloaded method over SOAP. Going by this, it would suggest that since scope specifiers are not a SOAP feature, WCF ignores it and goes by the OperationContract and DataMember attributes to decide the contracts.

Following also gets exposed as a DataMember of DataContract :

```
[DataMember]
private int _personAge;
```